# How to set the Jmeter properties in xml file

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am using below JMeter maven plugin in my POM.XML

```
<groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
<artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.7.0</version>
```

And if I want to execute the JMX file using maven command I updated my pom.xml file with below tags

Outside of my build block

```
<properties>
<my.host>localhost</my.host>
</properties>
```

in configuration block

```
<configuration>                       
<propertiesUser> 
<hostName>${my.host}</hostName> 
</propertiesUser> 
</configuration>
```

I run using below command to run JMeter using MVN

```
mvn verify  -Dmy.host=www.test.com
```

But I am not able to see the changes in my command window when I above command so is there anything that I want to add in my JMX file to run this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks good and you should be able to refer the property value via [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [__property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) functions where required.

If you want to print the property value to the console where you run Maven - you can go for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy). The relevant code will be something like:

```
${__groovy(println('Current hostName value:'+ props.get('hostName')),)}
```

And the output will be:

[image: JMeter Maven Property]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.